# Field currentActivity or type signature not found

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using unity 2019.4.24f1 and unity remote 5 app connected with USB.

```
var javaUnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
var currentActivity = javaUnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
```

This error is thrown from `currentActivity` line.

```
Exception: Field currentActivity or type signature  not found
UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetFieldID (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String fieldName, System.String signature, System.Boolean isStatic) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/AndroidJNI/AndroidJava.cs:1448)
UnityEngine.AndroidJNIHelper.GetFieldID (System.IntPtr javaClass, System.String fieldName, System.String signature, System.Boolean isStatic) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/AndroidJNI/AndroidJNI.bindings.cs:79)
UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetFieldID[ReturnType] (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String fieldName, System.Boolean isStatic) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/AndroidJNI/AndroidJava.cs:1361)
UnityEngine.AndroidJNIHelper.GetFieldID[FieldType] (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String fieldName, System.Boolean isStatic) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/AndroidJNI/AndroidJNI.bindings.cs:172)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._GetStatic[FieldType] (System.String fieldName) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/AndroidJNI/AndroidJava.cs:664)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.GetStatic[FieldType] (System.String fieldName) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/AndroidJNI/AndroidJava.cs:274)
```

Comment: Maybe you need to add your activity to the manifest? See the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881056/i-am-not-able-to-get-the-currentactivity-in-unity-and-i-am-getting-the-following

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone stuck with the same issue.
The emulator & unity remote 5 app connected with USB didn't work at least. But creating a apk build & running it on the android device was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Android plugin requires android device or emulator to set current activity.